# What are all the apple entries in my KeyChain?

Tags: keychain

In my KeyChain.app, there are a bunch of entries from Apple, like:

> com.apple.cloudd.deviceIdentifier.Production

Can I safely delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if you absolutely never use any iCloud services. You have to open each one to see exactly what part of iCloud it belongs to. You could have dozens of them, all doing different things. Honestly, I'd just leave them alone. They're taking up whole kilobytes of space.

e.g.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If I delete them all, will they not "regenerate", once I start using again some of those services?

Comment: You'd have to try it to see. I bet you'd end up having to log out of everything & back in again - known as the iCloud, iMessage, or FaceTime Hokey Cokey.  ['You log yer facetime in, yer facetime out… do the hokey cokey & shake it all about' Repeat for as many verses as unnecessary ;) All just to regenerate 20kb of nicely pre-cached, perfectly working data.

Comment: FYI it's called Hokey Pokey in the US.